# Rationale of Rails 5 Join Table Generated Defaults

Tags: join, indexing, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-generators

The Rails 5 command `rails g migration create_foo_bar_join_table` generates the following migration:

```
class CreateFooBarJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :foos, :bars do |t|
      # t.index [:foo_id, :bar_id]
      # t.index [:bar_id, :foo_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Why does the generator stub out two (bi-directional) indices with composite keys? Also why are they commented out? I'm confused by this and can't find any clear explanation for having these suggested defaults.

Are the above indices more lookup efficient than the ones below?

```
...
    create_join_table :foos, :bars do |t|
      t.index :foo_id
      t.index :bar_id
    end
...
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look into this deeper, maybe you have already taken a look at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/migration.rb#L25 for more on this?

Comment: Seems the composite indices are specifically for MySQL. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled on the exact answer reading the docs on `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

> It’s also a good idea to add indexes to each of those columns to speed
>   up the joins process. However, in MySQL it is advised to add a
>   compound index for both of the columns as MySQL only uses one index
>   per table during the lookup.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many